# Heroku Rails: "If you are the application owner check the logs for more information."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, production

So, my Rails app runs normally on dev mode. Then I pushed it successfully to Heroku. But then when I try to open any links on production mode, it crashes raising up that error on the title.
I already did some research and seems like my configs are correct. Where else could the problem be located?
Thanks

Comment: I did, but running the heroku migrations like suggested already solved it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to run your migrations directly to Heroku with the following command:

`heroku run rails db:migrate`

Worked for me.